# Einstein coefficient unit

Tags: dimensional-analysis, physical-chemistry, si-units

Einstein-A coefficient of diatomic molecule can be written as (W. A. Brown, 1970):

[image: Av'v"=32]

[unit]

A= 1/sec (transition probability, Einstein coefficient)

h-bar= Joule*Second (planck constant)

Re=Coulomb*meter (electronic dipole moment)

labmda=meter (wavelength)

q=dimensionless (Franck-Condon factor)

I couldn't get units of 1/sec when multiplying all elements of the term on the right.
what I missed it?

Comment: I'm suspecting other types of units are used. In SI units, the denominator should have the vacuum permittivity. Could you also provide a link to the article?

Comment: @sazan You can check the equation next link, W. A. Brown, 1970, equation 1 : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022407371901336/pdf?md5=40e326b13c891140dba626fc30363f6e&pid=1-s2.0-0022407371901336-main.pdf

Comment: @sazan Although the form of the equation varies slightly from paper to paper, they all use the same units. 
For example, G. Herzberg-diatomic molecule and Eq(7) in paper published by H. Nassar (2004): https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/37/14/005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, $R_{e}$ should be in atomic units, therefore in $ea_{0}$ where $a_{0}$ is the Bohr radius and the unit of length in this system.

The units of the equation above is then :
$$ \left[\frac{R_{e}^{2}}{\hbar \lambda^{3}}\right] = \frac{e^{2}a_{0}^{2}}{\hbar a_{0}^{3}} = \frac{e^2}{\hbar a_{0}}$$

Now, the factor $E_{H}=e^2/a_{0}$ is a Hartree, it's a unit of energy. You have finally:
$$ \left[\frac{R_{e}^{2}}{\hbar \lambda^{3}}\right] = \frac{E_{H}}{\hbar} $$

Which corresponds in atomic units to the inverse of the time unit ($t=\hbar/E_{H}$).

[The wiki page for hartree atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units)

Comment: I didn't think about Hartree atomic units to solve this problem. Thank you for letting me know. :)

Comment: Substituting a0 instead of lambda doesn't seem like a good idea. 
If it is a nitrogen molecule, what value should a0 be?

Comment: $a_{0}$ is just the unit of the wavelength. This is a dimensional analysis.